# Повторный запрос к серверу

Tags: http, клиент-сервер, веб-сервер

Клиент запрашивает с помощью HTTP страницу от сервера (+ заголовки и прочее) и получает её в ответ, но говорят, что если там есть картинки или другие файлы, то он делает ещё один запрос? Это правда так? Когда он делает повторный запрос на сервер? При наличии в html-коде отданой странички ссылки на файлы, которые размещены на сервере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это так. Клиент может получать от сервера разные ответы. И если это html, браузеру нужно вывести этот документ на экран, проходя по нему и строя дерево DOM. Если браузер обнаруживает в документе ссылки на ресурсы - он загружает их.

Каждый загруженный ресурс также обрабатывается. И, например, если в css браузер обнаруживает ссылки на другие ресурсы - он начинает загружать и их тоже. А если в них также попадаются ссылки на другие ресурсы - браузер запросит и их тоже.

Вы можете пронаблюдать за этим сами - откройте веб-инспектор в вашем браузере, например в Chrome, на вкладке Network:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая строка - запрос html-документа. Последующие - запросы ресурсов из документа, и затем ресурсов из ресурсов. Все по схеме, описанной выше.

> В ряде строк можно заметить надпись "Повторный-запрос-к-серверу". Фраза такая же, как название вашего вопроса. Возможно, вы хотели узнать именно об этом? Такая фраза в инспекторе (вместе со статусом 304) значит, что данный ресурс с сервера уже был закачан ранее, и с момента последней закачки не изменился. Значит смысла снова качать его - нет, и можно взять этот ресурс из кеша браузера.

Это называется http-кеширование, и реализуется за счет передачи в http-запросе заголовка `ETag`. При отдаче ресурса в первый раз, с ним передается некий ключ `Etag` (например, такой - `6d82cbb050ddc7fa9cbb659014546e59`), он формируется на сервере на основе содержимого запрашиваемого файла и даты его изменения. Сема такая:

1. Во время первого запроса браузер сохраняет файл и `ETag` в кеше
2. Во время повторного запроса браузер отсылает на сервер значение `ETag`
3. Если файл за это время не изменился, `ETag` у него будет такой же, как и в прошлый раз. Сервер сравнивает это значение `ETag` с пришедшим от браузера, и, если они одинаковые - не отправляет файл браузеру, а отправляет короткий статус 304.
4. По статусу 304 браузер понимает, что файл с прошлого запроса не был изменен, значит можно смело использовать этот файл из кеша.

Подробнее об этом вы можете прочесть в [этой статье от google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=ru).

Comment: Все понял. Большое спасибо.